# Get all elemenets form site using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i try to get all the elements from this site:
https://www.kw.com/agent/search/CA/San%20Diego

Using the following code:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__':
  WAIT = 3  
  print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
  options = Options()
  # options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
  
  link = f"https://www.kw.com/agent/search/CA/San%20Diego" 
  driver.get (link)   
  for i in range(1,50):
    print(f"Round {i}")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200000)")     
    time.sleep(WAIT)       
  soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'html.parser')       
  tmpDIV = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "FindAgentRoute__row"})     
  print(f"{len(tmpDIV)} elements found")  
  input("Press!")
```

But i don´t get all the elements form the site.
On the top of the site it says 1242 agents but i only get 1150.

How can i get all the agents elements from this site?

Comment: Have you tried by increasing the `WAIT` ? make it 30 or 60 and check ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add a scroll like below to your code where scrolling is done until we reach maximum scroll length so that you don't have to hardcode the scroll

```
 while True:
        # Scroll down to the bottom of the page
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        # Wait for the page to load
        time.sleep(5)
        # Check if we have reached the bottom of the page
        if driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight"):
            break
```

Full code for your example

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WAIT = 3
    print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    srv = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=srv, options=options)
    waitWD = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    link = f"https://www.kw.com/agent/search/CA/San%20Diego"
    driver.get(link)
    # Scroll down to the end of the page
    while True:
        # Scroll down to the bottom of the page
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        # Wait for the page to load
        time.sleep(5)
        # Check if we have reached the bottom of the page
        if driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight"):
            break

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    tmpDIV = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "FindAgentRoute__row"})
    print(f"{len(tmpDIV)} elements found")
    input("Press!")
```

Prints

```
1242 elements found
```